# How to include external js with static html using in node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I have inlcuded a static Html in `node.js`. In that html I want to import a js file.

I tried with:

```
<script src="some.js"></script>
```

But it actually does not get included.

How to make it work, please suggest?

Comment: are you using express.js?

Comment: no i am not using express.js ?

Comment: I recommend using express, and then you can make a folder your static directory and you can serve your javascript file easily

Comment: can you guide me how to do this using express ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Install express by this command:

```
npm install express
```

then create a folder named *public* in the directory where your server.js resides. Your directory structure should be like this:

```
server.js
public //public is a folder
  index.html
  javascript //javascript is also a folder
    some.js  //this is your javascript folder inside public/javascript folder
```

and do this in your **server.js**:

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http')
, var fs = require('fs');
, path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.configure(function () {
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

//create a route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('public/test.html');
});
```

And in your `html` include it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/some.js"></script>
```

Comment: `app.configure()` is no longer part of Express 4 (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37352626/10758800) S.O. answer